# Please help to identify the set this sticker belongs to

Tags: set-identification, sticker-identification

Please help to identify the set this sticker belongs to.

The sticker is on both sides of the ensemble.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bricklink lists this as a sticker over assembly

[Part # BA55pb01 : Stickered Assembly 4 x 1 x 2 with Arctic Technic Logo Pattern on Both Sides (Stickers) - Set 8640 - 2 Slopes 45 2 x 1, 1 Slope, Inverted 45 2 x 1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=BA55pb01#T=C&C=1)

From

[8640-1: Polar Copter](https://brickset.com/sets/8640-1/Polar-Copter)